# Need help with basic program in C

Tags: c, menu

I have a menu when i select 2 variables and then i must choose between a man and a woman. After that i must go to man.c or woman.c with the 2 variables previously choosed but i dont know how can i do that.

my main.c (only when the man option in the menu):

```
printf("Insert weight: ");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("Insert high: ");
scanf("%f",&b);
switch(opcion){
    case 'm':;
```

--here i want to go to man.c to continue with other menu but knowing variables weight and high--

man.c and woman.c are similars the ionly difference is when calculates the body mass index

man.c :

```
int bmi(float weight, float high){

    float bmi;
    char opcion;

    printf("a) Calculate body mass index");

    switch(opcion){

    case 'a': bmi = weight / high;
              break;

    }
}
```

now i ave only this and woman is the same. When is finished man.c and woman.c will have 4 options using weigh, high and some variables more that they asked when needed with scanf.

Comment: Can you explain more about what `man.c` and`woman.c` do? Showing code would be good as well. This will help us figure out what would be a good approach for you.

Comment: What you mean by going to man.c or woman.c....... You must call a function defined in man.c or woman.c......Follow @Eimantas answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you call a function (say `manMenu()`) and keep it in same .c file.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can't simply navigate through c files in C.
2) You can do that using includes & classes, but it's a bit hard for a beginner
3) The right way to do it is something like this:

```
 printf("M/F");
    scanf("%f",&option);    
    switch(option){
    case M:
      do_man();
      break;
    case F:
      do_woman();
      break;
    }
```

And you should declare the functions do_man() and do_woman() before the main.

Answer (score 1):

**General**:

- It's mistake about thinking about code in means of filenames. Instead you should think about functions.
- add error handling to the menu e.g. verify input and repeat in a loop until correct input or escape char.

**Solution**.

Add two functions `void handleMan(float weight ,float height);` and `void handleWoman(float weight ,float height);` prototypes to main.c (just copy code before `menu()` or `main()` and implement them in man.c and woman.c later on call right method upon user selection.

Comment: u mean something like that? 

main.c:

void handleMan(float weight, float height);
void handleWoman(float weight, float height);
int main(){
...
}

man.c:

void handleMan(float weight ,float height){
...
}

Comment: yes, this would be the simplest way to achieve your goal, although it seems to me that you don't need to have two separate functions to implement this - sex could be boolean parameter or enumeration passed to the function realizing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to call a gender specific function in the switch. For example man_menu() and woman_menu(). 
These could also be located in different .c files but then you need to link the object files together.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to define procedures for man and woman and  call procedure in switch statement and perform your individual activities in the respective methods .